# Transmission Daemon running under custom user trying to load config from wrong path

Tags: debian, transmission

I have transmission daemon 2.94 running as a service on a Debian 10 machine.

I changed the user running transmission daemon from default `debian-transmission` to `www-data` Apache user, since I want the save files to be readable by Apache and the opposite, Apache files to be readable by transmission.

To do that, I changed to the user setting from the following config files:

- `User=www-data` in `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service`
- `USER=www-data` in `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`
- `setuid www-data` and `setgid www-data` in `/etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf`

The transmission JSON config file still resides in `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`. I made sure both directories `/var/lib/transmission-daemon` and `/etc/transmission-daemon` were owned by the new user www-data.

But when I relaunch the service with `sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon` or `sudo service transmission-daemon start`, I get the following in the transmission logs:

```
Couldn't create "/var/www/.config": Permission denied (file-posix.c:189)
Couldn't read "/var/www/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json": No such file or directory (utils.c:238)
Couldn't save temporary file "/var/www/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json.tmp.jq3qtN": No such file or directory (variant.c:1285)
```

...and other similar errors.

So it would seem transmission-daemon is trying to use the `www-data` user home path and recreate its config directory here.

**Why is that and how can I make transmission using the previous default config path?** I don't see any transmission configuration depending on the user home path.

*Side question:* what is the difference between all those three config files where you set up the user running the service?

Answer (score 2):

Transmission-Daemon saves it's config to the home folder of the user it is running on.
In the default case for user `transmissio-daemon` the home folder is

`/var/lib/transmission-daemon` as it is defined in `/etc/passwd`

In Debian, the settings.json file found in
`/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/`
is just a symlink that points to `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`

Being a home folder is it supposed to be able to write in there.
The errors you receive are because transmission cannot write it's settings/stats in the home folder of the user it is running on.

However, i think the best approach to this is to use `umask` in settings.json to give access to others to files created by transmission and setup the download folder to a location that is reachable by you web-server (maybe a folder in /var/www with permissions to write in for transmission)

If you give more details regarding your use case maybe we can create a configuration that suits your needs without changing the user for transmission.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're thinking about `debian-transmission` user, not `transmissio-daemon`, even though the home folder path is very confusing. Anyway, I need the downloaded files to be saved in a specific folder that I have set in `settings.json`, and which is accessible to Apache user, and this folder is neither in `/var/www` (and must not be), neither in `debian-transmission` home folder. Regarding the errors, then should I move the `/var/lib/transmission/.config` to the Apache user folder maybe (with the appropriate change of rights of course)?

Comment: Regarding my side question, it's not about settings.com and its symlink (I get that), but about the difference of the user setting between `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`, `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service` and `/etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf`. It's quite confusing.

Comment: Anyway, I just moved the .config folder to /var/www/ Apache user home folder, with the appropriate rights, and everything works now.